# Menu Icon does not appear and links don't work

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, responsive-design

Im quite new to web design and am having trouble figuring out why my mobile dropdown menu works fine testing on a browser window, but when accessed using a mobile phone the black triangle denoting the 2nd list disappears and none of the links work; nothing happens when I touch them.

I've commented out the 'display:none' on the '#nav ul' selector so you can see how the menu functions, usually this would be uncommented.

Really appreciate any feedback, thanks.

```
<div id="nav">
    <img id="menubtn" src="images/menuIcon.png" alt="Menu button" />
    <ul>
       <li><a href="index.htm">Home</a></li>
       <li>Option 1 &#x25BE;
          <ul>
             <li><a href="">Option 1.1</a></li>
             <li id="bottomSub"><a href="">Option 1.2</a></li>
          </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a href="">Option 2</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Option 3</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Option 4</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Option 5</a></li>
       <li id="bottomNav"><a href="">Option 6</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>


/*--- All style--- */

body{
  background-color:lightblue;   
}

#nav{
  font-family:sans-serif;
  z-index:1;
}

#nav a{
  color:black;
}

#nav ul li{
  list-style:none;
  color:black; 
}

#nav li:hover ul{
  position:absolute;
  visibility:visible;
  display:block;
}

#nav a:hover{
   color:yellow;
}

#nav ul li a{
  text-decoration:none;
}

#nav ul ul{
  position:relative;
  display:none;
}






/* ----Mobile only---- */

@media screen and (max-width:480px){

#menubtn:hover + ul,#menubtn:focus + ul{
 display:block;
}

#nav ul {
  position:fixed;
  top:95px;
  background-color:#E5E5E5;
  font-size:0.8em;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width:120px;
  z-index:1;
  /*display:none;*/
 }

#nav ul li{
  border-left:1px solid black;  
  border-right:1px solid black;
  border-top:1px solid black;
  padding:0;
  padding:10px 4px;
}

#nav li:hover ul,#nav li:focus ul{
  top:50px;
  left:119px;
}

#nav ul ul li{
  font-size:1.2em;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  background-color:#E5E5E5;
  padding:10px 4px;
  width:130px;
}

#bottomSub, #bottomNav{
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

}
```

Comment: You work with hover on that menu, a touchscreen doesn't really emulate that..

Comment: On the previous version (which omitted the sub-menu) I found the :hover had the affect of showing the menu on touch and it remained on the screen until another part of the screen was touched; whereas the :focus did nothing. I tested this on android and ios. On this version the first menu still appeared as desired after touching the menu button when using just :hover, however something is stopping the links working and black triangle disappears.

Comment: @PatrickWallace can you share link of your page ?

Answer (score 0):

try by adding `<a>` tag on parent

```
<li><a href="#">Option 1 &#x25BE;</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="">Option 1.1</a></li>
         <li id="bottomSub"><a href="">Option 1.2</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
```

and display block to `<a>`

```
#nav ul li a {
  display:block;
}
```

If you give padding and other style to `<a>` tag it would be better because :focus doesn't work on li tag.

Not tested but might solve your problem

Comment: Tried adding <a> tags and display:block like so...      #nav li:hover ul li a,#nav li:focus ul li a{display:block;}       ....but this did not work. Then thought maybe z-index of the list items was being buried so added #nav ul li a{ z-index:1; }.  Anyone think Im on the right track with z-index and Im applying it slightly wrong?

Comment: No you are doing wrong as i said focus will not work on li do try #nav li:hover ul {display:block} a tag shoulb be block by default

Comment: actually i am talking to add <a> tag in Parent li tag where ul inside that above showing

Comment: Still behaving exactly the same. When clicking the links it doesnt turn yellow as it should and actually makes the menu bar dissapear again as if I pressed anywhere on the background. This is why I thought it might be a z-index issue, but to no avail yet. Is it ok to post links to websites here so you can see the behaviour first hand?

Comment: www.duncanwallacemassage.com

Comment: @PatrickWallace oh man it will definitely not work because when u tab on dropdown u lost the focus / hover now in your case u need to use javascript / jQuery for toggle menu

Comment: The hover/focus behaviour is different from desktop actually its not like as u aspected . See your website in chrome emulator might u understand what i want to say thanks